# keep Sending all pending data to the server after the QTcpSocket is closed Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I developed a client-server program using the great Qt Framework.my problem is:

In the client side I have a `QMainWindow` in which I defined a `QTcpSocket` in order to exchange data with the server.

Before closing the `QMainWindow` I have to send to the server that a specified client is disconnected. I do that by implementing the `closeEvent` method. But when I close the `QMainWindow` it seems that the socket is closed also and all pending data is lost.

So how to check if all data were sent to the server before the `QMainWindow` was closed or simply avoiding to close the socket until all remaining data is sent.

Qt Code :

```
void FenetreRoom::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    event->ignore() ;
    QDataStream out(&paquet, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QString messageAEnvoyer ="out"+nameVisiter+"/"+QString::number(idUser)+"/"+QString::number(posActuelle);
    out << (quint16) 0;
    out << messageAEnvoyer;
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << (quint16) (paquet.size() - sizeof(quint16));        
    socket->write(paquet);                   
    event->accept();
}
```

Comment: what does `socket->write(paquet);` return?

Comment: Try `socket->waitForBytesWritten()`  after write.

Comment: thanks a lot Alexander Medvidov it works very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `socket->waitForBytesWritten();` after write.